# Transform-to-center animation in horizontal list

Tags: windows-phone-7, animation

I have an horizontal listbox of many images. Now I need whenever I choose an image not at center. It will slide to center of listbox (not jump). Can anyone give me the solution ? Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [ScrollToHorizontalOffset](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.scrollviewer.scrolltohorizontaloffset%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)?

If you have specific requirements about how the animation should look you'll need to do this yourself though.